# Multitenancy is not working in my JHIpster application

Tags: jhipster

I have followed some links to create multi-tenancy in my JHipster application,but its not working.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy

https://github.com/jgasmi/jhipster-mt/

I did following:

**Added following in my application-dev.yml:**

```
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myApp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: root
    password: root
    serverName: localhost
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    properties:
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
        hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver : com.mycompany.myapp.multitenancy.TenantIdentifierResolver
        hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider : com.mycompany.myapp.multitenancy.SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
        hibernate.multiTenancy : SCHEMA
```

**My TenantIdentifierResolver class:**

```
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        
        return "myapp2";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
    
    
}
```

**And my class SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl looks as follows:**

```
public class SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl  implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService
{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchemaMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.class);
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("USE myapp2;");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        log.warn("Get Connection for Tenatd is:"+tenantIdentifier);
        final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
        /*
         * try { connection.setCatalog(tenantIdentifier); //
         * connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + tenantIdentifier + ";"); //
         * connection.setCatalog(tenantIdentifier); //
         * connection.setSchema(tenantIdentifier); } catch (SQLException e) { throw new
         * HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" +
         * tenantIdentifier + "]", e); }
         */
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
//        try {
//            connection.createStatement().execute("USE "+tenantIdentifier+";");
//        }
//        catch (SQLException e) {
//            throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
//        }
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
        Map lSettings = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings();
        DataSource localDs =  (DataSource) lSettings.get("hibernate.connection.datasource");
        dataSource = localDs;
    }
}
```

I am just trying to see first that it should work, and then I can change it to be based on tenant logic, schema tenancy logic or database tenancy logic.

When I run the application following is the logs:

```
D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy>mvnw -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.myapp:my-app >--------------------------
[INFO] Building My App 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.7:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ my-app >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-versions) @ my-app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-dependencyConvergence) @ my-app ---
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.testcontainers:mysql:1.15.3
    +-org.testcontainers:jdbc:1.15.3
      +-org.testcontainers:database-commons:1.15.3
        +-org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.3
          +-org.rnorth.visible-assertions:visible-assertions:2.1.2
            +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.2.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.testcontainers:mysql:1.15.3
    +-org.testcontainers:jdbc:1.15.3
      +-org.testcontainers:database-commons:1.15.3
        +-org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.3
          +-com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-zerodep:3.2.8
            +-net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.5.2.Final paths to dependency are:
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:2.4.7
    +-io.undertow:undertow-core:2.2.8.Final
      +-org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.8.0.Final
        +-org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.5.2.Final
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:2.4.7
    +-io.undertow:undertow-core:2.2.8.Final
      +-org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.8.0.Final
        +-org.wildfly.client:wildfly-client-config:1.0.1.Final
          +-org.wildfly.common:wildfly-common:1.2.0.Final

[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0 paths to dependency are:
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.7
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.7
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
        +-org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2
          +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.7
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.7
    +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
      +-org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine:0.19.0
    +-com.tngtech.archunit:archunit-junit5-engine-api:0.19.0
      +-org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.2
        +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:problem-violations:0.26.2
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:problem-spring-common:0.26.2
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
and
+-com.myapp:my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.26.2
    +-org.zalando:faux-pas:0.8.0
      +-org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ my-app ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\sachin\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.7\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.7-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\java-project\\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\\sample\\multitennnacy\\target\\jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0.0:read-project-properties (default) @ my-app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- checksum-maven-plugin:1.10:files (default) @ my-app ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:3.0.0:run (eval-frontend-checksum) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO]      [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\target
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:install-node-and-npm (install-node-and-npm) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Node v14.17.1 is already installed.
[INFO] NPM 7.18.1 is already installed.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (npm install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Skipping execution.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.0:npm (webapp build dev) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Skipping execution.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 81 source files to D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\target\classes
[INFO] /D:/java-project/jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace/sample/multitennnacy/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/multitenancy/ConnectionProviderFactory.java: D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\src\main\java\com\mycompany\myapp\multitenancy\ConnectionProviderFactory.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /D:/java-project/jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace/sample/multitennnacy/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/multitenancy/ConnectionProviderFactory.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 29 source files to D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\target\test-classes
[INFO] /D:/java-project/jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace/sample/multitennnacy/src/test/java/com/myapp/service/MailServiceIT.java: D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\src\test\java\com\myapp\service\MailServiceIT.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /D:/java-project/jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace/sample/multitennnacy/src/test/java/com/myapp/service/MailServiceIT.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.7:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ my-app <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.7:run (default-cli) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
        ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
        ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
  ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
  ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
   ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 2.4.7 ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::

2021-07-14 10:46:05.956 DEBUG 24976 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
2021-07-14 10:46:05.988  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.MyApp                          : Starting MyApp using Java 11.0.11 on SACHIN-MSI with PID 24976 (D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy\target\classes started by sachin in D:\java-project\jhipsterptest-eclipse-workspace\sample\multitennnacy)
2021-07-14 10:46:05.989 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.MyApp                          : Running with Spring Boot v2.4.7, Spring v5.3.8
2021-07-14 10:46:05.989  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.MyApp                          : The following profiles are active: dev,api-docs
2021-07-14 10:46:09.018 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] i.m.c.u.i.logging.InternalLoggerFactory  : Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2021-07-14 10:46:09.217 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Registering CORS filter
2021-07-14 10:46:09.283  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Web application configuration, using profiles: dev
2021-07-14 10:46:09.283  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.config.WebConfigurer           : Web application fully configured
2021-07-14 10:46:09.570 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.592 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.595 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.core.Ehcache-com.myapp.domain.User   : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.599 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.myapp.domain.Authority           : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.602 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.myapp.domain.User.authorities    : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.605 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-com.myapp.domain.Tenant    : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.608 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.Ehcache-com.myapp.domain.DbType    : Initialize successful.
2021-07-14 10:46:09.622 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.config.AsyncConfiguration      : Creating Async Task Executor
2021-07-14 10:46:09.692 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.config.LiquibaseConfiguration  : Configuring Liquibase
2021-07-14 10:46:09.829  WARN 24976 --- [  my-app-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2021-07-14 10:46:11.299 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.security.jwt.TokenProvider     : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
2021-07-14 10:46:12.920 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] t.j.c.apidoc.SpringfoxAutoConfiguration  : Starting OpenAPI docs
2021-07-14 10:46:12.927 DEBUG 24976 --- [  restartedMain] t.j.c.apidoc.SpringfoxAutoConfiguration  : Started OpenAPI docs in 5 ms
2021-07-14 10:46:13.623  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] org.jboss.threads                        : JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final
2021-07-14 10:46:14.116  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.MyApp                          : Started MyApp in 8.783 seconds (JVM running for 9.535)
2021-07-14 10:46:14.124  INFO 24976 --- [  restartedMain] com.myapp.MyApp                          :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'myApp' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080/
        External:       http://192.168.43.1:8080/
        Profile(s):     [dev, api-docs]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**There are no error logs, but browser shows this.**

[image]

Seems like I am missing something small, but not ablw to find it out.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not related to multitenancy. It looks like you did not follow instructions to run your app in dev, this is what is explained in the error page and also in your project's README.md and in official docs at https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Comment: Dear Gaël
Thanks for your amazing response.
Though my application is workign absoultely fine beofre trying to introduce this multi-tenancy feature. I have based my application stack on react frontend jfyi.

Could you please help me out in pin-pointing what you see as a problem in my setup? Or should some more info on setup/code from my can help better diagnosing it? If so which particular files/code?

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: React or Angular, it's the same way of working. Your issue is not about setup or code it's about following instructions to build, run and access your app. Have you read your README.md and https://www.jhipster.tech/development/